# 12AX7 Valve Overdrive/Distortion Effect Pedal

Tags: preamp, guitar-pedal, tube

I'm following the schematic below using the recommendations plus a couple of extra LEDs. With the footswitch in the enabled position, I'm not getting any sound. In the bypass position, the input and output sockets are connected as expected.

The valve I am using is very old so could be faulty, is there any way to reliably test it or is there anything I have missed in my variation on the original?

[image: Tube driver original]

My version:

[image: Valve driver]

Comment: ...where are you generating your plate voltage?

Comment: Things to check: Heaters glowing? Anode voltage? (Should be about half the supply (9V) : use the voltage across the anode resistors to compute teh anode current.

Comment: @Hearth - totally forgot to put the link in from R4 to the junction between R7 and R8. Also, the original schematic doesn't show where the 4558 is powered from?

Comment: @JoeMann I'm more concerned about whether 9V is even enough for a tube amplifier, they tended to run at much higher voltages.

Comment: @Hearth - Agreed but I think in this case with it being a distortion pedal, lower voltages can be used. The original design is based on this - https://patents.google.com/patent/US5022305A/en

Comment: @Hearth it's not uncommon to see such astonishingly low voltages on tubes like this, when the goal is either convenience or signal processing more than amplification.  (There were automotive tubes in the 1950's designed for 12V on the plate, but that's a different story -- they tended to have "12E" numbers).

Comment: The patent appears to place both 12 V heater elements **in-series** and supplied by 9 V. Which means to me "not many electrons are boiled off." The patent also claims that their "invention provides a rich, warm distortion emphasizing even harmonics" while later admitting in the conclusions that "the reasons for these advantageous results are not fully understood." The [12AX7 datasheet](http://www.philbrickarchive.org/12ax7_sylvania.pdf) may be worth a gander. I'm not even slightly interested in considering why said circuit may not work for the OP.

Comment: @jonk: the 12AX7 has a single center-tapped 12 V heater element, so this circuit runs the 12 V heater at 9 V.  The two halves of the 12 volt heater were often used in parallel on 6 Volts.

Comment: @PeterBennett Ah. It's been 40 years for me and I didn't check the datasheet for that "series/parallel" specification. I see it now. Thanks! There will be a few more electrons boiled off, now.

Comment: @PeterBennett But I wonder how good when at lower voltage. I remember when working on controlling the temperature of tungsten, electrophoretically coated with LaB6 and annealed, filaments behind a Wehnelt used in photolithography applications, the difference in temperature between, say, 2100 K and 2050 K, was the difference between very poor and very good operation. NIST calibrated methods had to be used and verified (on a regular basis, too) to maintain good operation and lifetime. (A little hotter got a nice beam, but then the $80k head had to be replaced every few months instead of years.)

Comment: Never mind the tube.  Are you supplying power to U1?  I don't see it mentioned in either the original circuit or in your version.

Comment: @JRE - Something I noticed after I posted was U1 doesn't have a supply. I will try supplying it with 12 volts. Schoolboy error.

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in supplying the plates of the 12AX7 and the 4558 correctly (adding connections to 12v in my case). The latter omitted from the original design. Rookie error, but it is now working well.